# Avoid getting back DocumentDb system properties

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a query which returns one document

Select * from root

Above query also returns extra system properties like _ts, _self, _etag etc. I do not want my query to return those extra properties. And I want * as I do not want to specify columns to select.

I am running this query in sproc. Any better way to not return system properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do that. It will not take up a significant amount of resources to get them and you can always just ignore them. Alternatively, you can delete them as soon as the document(s) arrive using code like this:

```
for (var _i = 0, var _len = resultsArray.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  var row = resultsArray[_i];
  delete row._ts;
  delete row._self;
  delete row._etag;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to pass these information to UI. SelfLink is critical information to expose to UI. I can remove them in service layer, but I was wondering if DocumentDb provide me something to remove them before returning response.setBody(document) back to service layer.

Comment: So, remove them in your sproc before returning to your calling code. I suspect that you are doing some other manipulation anyway, otherwise, why use a sproc? I'll edit the answer with example code on how to delete them. Note, you may not want to delete the _etag. It's useful to avoid a conflict if the document is edited between the read and your write.

Comment: Thanks. I able to use delete documentsRead[i]._self and it worked.